# Edit after questions deletion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, deleted-questions

I found [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/shors-algorithm-and-quantum-computer) now deleted question in first-posts review. Somehow @MARKDOWN was able to edit the question after it was deleted:

[image: WHY?????????]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reviewed this question in the 'first posts' review queue, shortly after which, it got deleted.

However, *before* it was deleted, an edit was suggested. This placed it in the edit queue.

Now, a question can still be edited after it's deleted (with the right privileges), so the question *stays* in the 'suggested edit' queue, even though it has already been deleted.

In this case, the edit got approved *after* the question got deleted, although the edit was suggested *before* the question got deleted.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for investigating this. I wouldn’t have wondered if I would have been able to see the rev history but no problem. Maybe add [status-bydesign]